# Updating dimensions of a rotated view

Tags: android, android-layout, rotation, android-view

I have several `Switch` views in my app that have been rotated 270 degrees. The dimensions of the switch are, however, still laid out based on the original orientation (as expected in Android layouts):

[image]

How can I flip the width and height of the switch? I've not been able to find a way in the layout XML, and attempts to do so programmatically in the containing fragment have failed, as the returned width and height (even in `onCreateView()` and `onViewCreated()`) is always 0. I am aware that getting a 0 width and height is usually caused by querying too early, but, if a programmatic approach is needed to solve this problem, where should I actually execute the code to flip the dimensions?

Comment: did you try with static hight `android:layout_height="60dp"`

Comment: I can statically at the height, but I want to use the same values that would be used in the horizontal orientation. How do I get these?

Answer (score 0):

Try to `requestLayout()` on your switches or swap the width and height in layoutParams of switches.

Comment: How would one swap the width and height via layoutParams?